# Actualizar datos pide tener conexion abierta

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este error de antemano muchas gracias.

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de 3 capas pero al momento de actualizar mis datos desde la aplicación web a  la base de datos me manda este mensaje.

```
//** ExecuteNonQuery requiere una conexión abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.
```

Este es mi código, lo tengo en la misma clase.

```
//** Esta es mi cadena de conexión
   private string opcion_cadenaconexion()
    {
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd_Ventas"].ConnectionString;

    }

 ///** Este es mi método que utilizo al actualizar los datos.
  private SqlCommand conexion_open(string commantext, SqlParameter[] commandparameters)
    {
        string conexion = opcion_cadenaconexion();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion);

        SqlCommand cmd; 
            try
           {
            //*** Aquí abro la conexión
            con.Open(); 
            cmd = new SqlCommand(commantext, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            agregar_parameter(cmd, commandparameters);

           }
           finally
            {
              //*** Aquí cierro la conexión
                con.Close();
            }

            return cmd;

    }

  //** Este es el método que utilizo al actualizar mis datos a la bd donde recibe como parámetros el procedimiento almacenado y los parámetros
  public void ExecuteDataTable(string commantext, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
           //*** Aqui mando a llamar al método de arriba conexion_open
            da.UpdateCommand = conexion_open(commantext, commandParameters);
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }

  //*****  Aquí mando a traer mi método anterior en otra clase.

  public void Actualizar_Datos(int id_persona, string nombre, string no_empleado)
    {
        SqlParameter[] sqlparameter = 
        { 
            new SqlParameter ("@Id_persona",SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlParameter ("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar,100),
            new SqlParameter ("@no_empleado", SqlDbType.VarChar,50)

        };

        sqlparameter[0].Value = id_persona;
        sqlparameter[1].Value = nombre;
        sqlparameter[2].Value = no_empleado;

         ///*** "Actualiza_Datos" es el nombre del procedimiento almacenado
        _conexion.ExecuteDataTable("Actualiza_Datos", sqlparameter);

    }
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a resolver esto?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: creo que la estructura de tu codigo no es la correcta.

Comment: puedes revisar el estado de tu conexion asi con.State = ConnectionState.Open; y si es abierta la cierras  o lo contrario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que en tu método conexión_open estas abriendo y al mismo tiempo cerrando la conexión y es se requiere abierta para  tu método `UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`,

Ejemplo:

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
 //*** Aqui mando a llamar al método de arriba conexion_open
  da.UpdateCommand = conexion_open(commantext, commandParameters);
 da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 // aquí debería ir tu cierre de conexión
```

o prueba agregando `ExecuteNonQuery` dentro de tu método conexión después de `agregar_parameter`

```
//*** Aquí abro la conexión
con.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
cmd = new SqlCommand(commantext, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
agregar_parameter(cmd, commandparameters);
da.UpdateCommand=cmd;
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

creo que lo recomendable es reestructurar el diseño de tu código

Comment: Hola @JuanCarlosHdz sabes como puedo hacer para cerrar la conexion despues del  **da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();** gracias.

Comment: @SHINOBI Como te comento lo recomendable es reestructurar el código ya que por ejemplo tu método conexion_open por su definición tiene operaciones que no le corresponden

Answer (score 0):

Falta un return

```
   private string opcion_cadenaconexion()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd_Ventas"].ConnectionString;

}
```

Debe de return connection;